# how to write correct JSON string file in swift

Tags: json

i have created a JSON string file which contains

```
{
[{"teamName":"Arsenal",
 "image":"Arsenal",
 "nextMatch":"in 2 days",
 "matches":[{"oppositeTeam":"teamName",
            "matchTimings":"121212",
            "matchId":"ID 213432"},
            {"oppositeTeam":"teamName",
            "matchTimings":"121212",
            "matchId":"ID 213432"}],

 "fixtures": {"oppositeTeam":"teamName",
 "oppositeTeamScore":"7",
 "homeTeamScore":"4",
 "homeTeamCards":"True",
 "oppositeTeamCards":"false",
 "fixtureId":"ID 213432”}
 }},
 {"teamName":"Chelsea",
 "image":"Chelsea",
 "nextMatch":"in 2 days",
 "matches":{"oppositeTeam":"teamName",
            "matchTimings":"121212",
            "matchId":"ID 213432"},

 "fixtures": {"oppositeTeam":"teamName",
 "oppositeTeamScore":"7",
 "homeTeamScore":"4",
 "homeTeamCards":"True",
 "oppositeTeamCards":"false",
 "fixtureId":"ID 213432”}
 }},{
 "teamName":"India",
 "image":"India",
 "nextMatch":"in 2 days",
 }
 ] }
```

but when i checked this JSON on online Json reader it shows many errors and i am new to json parsing and dont know how to correct json

Comment: what is the question ? and what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: i dont have API so i am trying to build a JSON file inside my project so that i can parse data from that file , but i dont konw how to write JSON in correct format

Comment: i could help you write one, but not understand one i will leave an article to explain json are you interested in that answer or just a corret syntax ?

Comment: i want to learn so that i can do it by myself in future @Tobi

Comment: check out my latest answer. would help you

Comment: For one project, I've had to bury a file inside a Playground inline, but it really a bad approach... I used a multi-line string literal, but for JSON, the escaping problems maybe unsolvable, hence I'm not putting that in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Correct JSON syntax:

```
{
   "teams":[
      {
         "teamName":"Arsenal",
         "image":"Arsenal",
         "nextMatch":"in 2 days",
         "matches":[
            {
               "oppositeTeam":"teamName",
               "matchTimings":"121212",
               "matchId":"ID 213432"
            },
            {
               "oppositeTeam":"teamName",
               "matchTimings":"121212",
               "matchId":"ID 213432"
            }
         ],
         "fixtures":{
            "oppositeTeam":"teamName",
            "oppositeTeamScore":"7",
            "homeTeamScore":"4",
            "homeTeamCards":"True",
            "oppositeTeamCards":"false",
            "fixtureId":"ID 213432"
         }
      },
      {
         "teamName":"Chelsea",
         "image":"Chelsea",
         "nextMatch":"in 2 days",
         "matches":{
            "oppositeTeam":"teamName",
            "matchTimings":"121212",
            "matchId":"ID 213432"
         },
         "fixtures":{
            "oppositeTeam":"teamName",
            "oppositeTeamScore":"7",
            "homeTeamScore":"4",
            "homeTeamCards":"True",
            "oppositeTeamCards":"false",
            "fixtureId":"ID 213432"
         }
      },
      {
         "teamName":"India",
         "image":"India",
         "nextMatch":"in 2 days"
      }
   ]
}
```

Your errors were not having a key for the overall array, using typographer quotes on the closing of the matchIds and extra closing braces.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to learn so that i can do it by myself in future

Well, to write a valid `JSON`  100% without any big problems, i would suggest [`Codable`](https://medium.com/xcblog/painless-json-parsing-with-swift-codable-2c0beaeb21c1),

Now for any manually or locally written `JSON`, I would

1- Create a struct that confirms to `Codable` .

2- Create an instance of that `Object` .

3- `Encode` that object, and just convert it to `String` and it will 100% confirm to `JSON` verifiers .

Observe the code Below.

```
struct MyOject: Codable {
    var param1: String
    var param2: Int
    var param3: String
}

let myObj = MyOject(param1: "foo", param2: 1, param3: "bee")
let encodedData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(myObj) // encode the object as JSON Data
let myJSON = String(data:encodedData, encoding: .utf8)! // converting to String that is indeed JSON formatted
print(myJSON)

//Now to use it as object again we just need to Decode it. (the data)

let myObjResult = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyOject.self, from: encodedData) // converted back as object
print(myObj.param1) // test reuslt should be (foo)
```

Now what are the benefits

1- The most important thing reusability you can reuse it as much as you need.

2- 100% valid `JSON` provider.

3- Gives you a big skill in the future to handle the `Responses` from any API.

4-  This is by far the easiest way to do so and the fastest.